# Profiler not working connecting to my application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, profiler, fdt

I have tried running the profiler with my app before in Flash Builder and it did not work. The Profiler would connect successfully to my application, but the application never appeared. It was just a blank window (which I suspect was the ProfilerAgent). I see the memory start to spike, but after a couple seconds it just flattens out and it never appears to load my application inside the profiler agent. No errors are reported at any time...

- I tried profiling in FDT and the exact same thing happens.
- I also tried profiling a new project from scratch and it does the same thing.
- It just looks like the ProfilerAgent just can't connect to the application...
- This is an AIR app and Im not sure if that has anything to do with it.

What should I do? **(I've tried all the regular workarounds, most of which are useful if you get the "profiler can't connect" error which I am not getting).**

Comment: Please provide a bit more info: What does the console say (add info to this question)? Any screenshots? Is there any ADL process running? Tell us about your app - '... but the application never appeared' this is interesting. Are you using the Flex Framework? Sounds like it. What you described 'memory goes up - then flattens' is expected when a profiler connects to an and the app starts up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was targeting the Flex 4.5 sdk in Flash Builder 4.6. For some reason if I target the 4.6 sdk then it profiles fine.

Comment: Was this in FDT or Flash Builder? Did you switch IDEs?

Comment: yes, correction I did switch IDEs, still was not able to profile in FDT.